# AWS how can I check docker logs in ECS Fargate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a container with `Stopped | Exit code: 0`. How can I debug this? I can't see any logs in CloudWatch (probably because it didn't get to generate any, I did add logConfiguration in the task definition). Is there a way to access docker logs in ECS Fargate?

Answer (score 2):

When you run containers on ECS Fargate, it will post all `stdout` logs to Cloudwatch Logs. You can find the documentation on how to define that in your task definition [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html).

In addition to defining the `awslogs` driver as explained above, you will also need to make sure you have permissions to put logs in Cloudwatch Logs by [giving your execution role the permissions it needs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html).

Then, assuming the container posts all logs to `stdout` (it should if it follows the [12-factor app pattern](https://12factor.net/)) then you should see the logs in the log group you define in your task definition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It connects to Cloudwatch, I can see the log group of my task definition there. However, it is not logging anything. Maybe because the container never started? That's why I need to find the docker logs. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlejandroVeintimilla docker logs are the same as what would be put into cloudwatch logs. Have you tried running your container locally? Are you sure that it even outputs any logs? From your question, exit codes of 0 usually indicate a successful run.

Comment: I think it had something to do with environment variables. I repeated the whole process, hard coding some environment variables, removing docker-compose, and changing a bit of the Dockerfile. Not sure what solved it but suspect it was the environment variables. Of course, I'll hide them, just not yet.